# How to calculate area of drawn polygon of React native mapbox GL?

Tags: react-native, mapbox-gl-js, turfjs, react-native-mapbox-gl

Below is the example of drawn polygon and how to calculate the area of the polygon ?
I need help to calculate are of polygon using turf.js
Like currently in mapbox GL js they have similar functionality of drawing map https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-draw/ and calculating are for same.

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";
 import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Image } from "react-native";
 import MapboxGL from "@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps";
 
 MapboxGL.setAccessToken(
   "pk.eyJ1IjoiZGVla3NoYW1laHRhMTI1IiwiYSI6ImNrcWV6OWE0bDBjcmMydXF1enZqMjd5MDMifQ.hFB7SI_kojKYfNQ42c62BA"
 );
 
 const App = () => {
   const [coordinates] = useState([78.9629, 20.5937]);
   const [route, setRoute] = useState({
     type: "FeatureCollection",
     features: [
       {
         type: "Feature",
         properties: {},
         geometry: {
           type: "LineString",
           coordinates: [
             [77.5946, 12.9716],
             [80.2707, 13.0827],
           ],
         },
       },
     ],
   });
 
   const [polygon, setPolygon] = useState({
     type: "Feature",
     geometry: {
       type: "Polygon",
       coordinates: [
         [
           [72.685547, 20.055931],
           [76.640625, 21.207458],
           [76.904297, 17.978733],
           [72.685547, 20.055931],
         ],
       ],
     },
   });
   const renderAnnotations = () => {
     return (
       <MapboxGL.PointAnnotation
         key="pointAnnotation"
         id="pointAnnotation"
         coordinate={[74, 27]}
       >
         <View
           style={{
             height: 30,
             width: 30,
             backgroundColor: "red",
             borderRadius: 50,
             borderColor: "#fff",
             borderWidth: 3,
           }}
         />
       </MapboxGL.PointAnnotation>
     );
   };
 
   return (
     <View style={styles.page}>
       <View style={styles.container}>
         <MapboxGL.MapView style={styles.map} onPress={() => console.log("test")}>
           <MapboxGL.Camera zoomLevel={4} centerCoordinate={coordinates} />
           <MapboxGL.PointAnnotation coordinate={coordinates} />
           <View>{renderAnnotations()}</View>
           <MapboxGL.MarkerView id={"marker"} coordinate={[72, 23]}>
             <View>
               <View style={styles.markerContainer}>
                 <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                   <Text style={styles.text}>{"Gujarat"}</Text>
                 </View>
                 {/* <Image
                   source={require("./location.jpeg")}
                   style={{
                     width: 20,
                     height: 30,
                     backgroundColor: "red",
                     resizeMode: "cover",
                   }}
                 /> */}
               </View>
             </View>
           </MapboxGL.MarkerView>
           <MapboxGL.ShapeSource id="line1" shape={route}>
             <MapboxGL.LineLayer
               id="linelayer1"
               style={{ lineColor: "red", lineWidth: 5 }}
             />
           </MapboxGL.ShapeSource>
           <MapboxGL.ShapeSource id="source" shape={polygon}>
             <MapboxGL.FillLayer
               id="fill"
               style={{ fillColor: "blue", fillOpacity: 0.7 }}
             />
             <MapboxGL.LineLayer
               id="line"
               style={{ lineColor: "red", lineWidth: 2 }}
             />
           </MapboxGL.ShapeSource>
         </MapboxGL.MapView>
       </View>
     </View>
   );
 };
 
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   page: {
     flex: 1,
   },
   container: {
     height: "100%",
     width: "100%",
     flex: 1,
   },
   markerContainer: {
     alignItems: "center",
     width: 60,
     backgroundColor: "transparent",
     height: 70,
   },
   map: {
     flex: 1,
   },
   textContainer: {
     backgroundColor: "white",
     borderRadius: 10,
     flex: 1,
     flexDirection: "row",
     alignItems: "center",
   },
   text: {
     textAlign: "center",
     paddingHorizontal: 5,
     flex: 1,
   },
   icon: {
     paddingTop: 10,
   },
 });
 
 export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

just pass the geometry to the area function https://turfjs.org/docs/#area

```js
import * as Turf from '@turf/turf';
...
const area = Turf.area(polygon.geometry) // area in m2
```